# How should I implement a wait-notify approach for a game?

Tags: java, java-threads

I have to implement a game with three players. I have the classes: player, game, board and edge. The board is a complete graph and each player must extract an edge. When the graph becomes a spanning tree a player wins. I implement the game with threads but I can't figure it out how I should implement a wait-notify approach.The examples found on the internet show only two threads. The wait should be in run method or I should create a new method for wait() and notify() ?I should have a run method in game class? Or just in player class?

Game Class:

```
public class Game {

    private Board board;
    private Player winner;
    private Edge edges;
    private final List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addPlayer(Player player) {
        players.add(player);
        player.setGame(this);
    }

    public void setWinner(Player winningPlayer) {
        int maxPoints = 0;
        this.winner = winningPlayer;
        for (Player p : players) {
            maxPoints += p.getPoints();
            p.setPoints(0);
        }
        winningPlayer.setPoints(maxPoints);
    } 

    public Board getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void start () {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < getPlayers().size(); i++) {
            new Thread(getPlayers().get(i)).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Board Class:

```
public class Board {
    private final Graph complete;

    public Board() {
        complete = new Graph();
    }

    public Board(int size) {
        // create the complete graph
        this.complete = new Graph(size);
        // shuffle its edges
        Collections.shuffle(complete.getEdges());
    }

    public synchronized Edge extract() {
        Edge edge = complete.getEdges().getFirst();
        complete.getEdges().removeFirst();
        return edge;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return complete.getEdges().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Player Class:

```
public class Player implements Runnable{

    private String name;
    private Game game;
    private Graph graph = new Graph();
    private int points;
    private static final int THINKING_TIME = 20;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private boolean play() throws InterruptedException {
        Board board = game.getBoard();
        if (board.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        graph.add( board.extract() );
        System.out.println(name + ": " + graph);
        Thread.sleep(THINKING_TIME);

        if (graph.isSpanningTree()) { 
            game.setWinner(this);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public Game getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public void setGame(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            play();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("error: " + this.name + "'s turn was interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

I only included the relevant classes for this question

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you've taken the [tour] and read [what is on-topic](/help/on-topic) you probably already know that SO isn't a general help forum, and "I want to [...] how do I do that?" questions mean it's [too early](/help/how-to-ask) to post. If you haven't written code yet, and you need with getting started, this is not the right place yet: instead, pick an approach (or pick multiple approaches and compare them!) and then once you've written code, and you made some headway, and you get stuck, and debugging isn't gaining you any insight, that's when SO is the right place to ask.

Comment: I really try to solve my problem but I don't find a way so I came here to ask for an idea.

Comment: Prefer using concurrency utilities to wait and notify. Take a look at the packages at java.util.concurrent

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simplifying the task,

- we have a board and a queue of players, and
- we just must let a player on this board one by one in some given order:
  one enters, makes a move, leaves and only then the following can embark.

Board looks pretty much like a *shared resource*, so we definitely must synchronize the process on it.

Board does nothing, but players do. So the players will *wait* and *notify*.
 A player

- can define if it is one's turn or not
- *wait* if not (literally) - some another not-waiting player can try
- then make a move on the board and leaves (id est *notify all* interested parties to resume trying)

Here is a short example, where board manages the queue oneself. It's runnable but does not solve your precise task. Just illustrates the idea.

```java
    public class Game {

    private static class PlayBoard {

        private int movesLeft;
        private List<Player> players;
        private int playerToMove;

        PlayBoard(int movesLeft) {
            this.movesLeft = movesLeft;
        }

        void setParties(Player... players) {
            this.players = Arrays.asList(players);
            this.players.forEach((Player player) -> player.prepareForGame(this));
            playerToMove = 0;
        }

        boolean isActive() {
            return movesLeft > 0;
        }

        boolean canIMove(Player player) {
            return players.get(playerToMove) == player;
        }

        void takeMove(Player player) {
            playerToMove = players.indexOf(player);
            movesLeft--;
            System.out.printf("%s's making move. %d moves left\n", player.name, movesLeft);
            playerToMove = (playerToMove + 1) % players.size();
        }
    }

    private static class Player {

        private final String name;
        private PlayBoard playBoard;

        Player(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        void prepareForGame(PlayBoard playBoard) {
            this.playBoard = playBoard;
        }

        void play() {
            synchronized (playBoard) {
                while (playBoard.isActive()) {
                    if (playBoard.canIMove(this)) {
                        playBoard.takeMove(this);
                        playBoard.notifyAll();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            playBoard.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        PlayBoard playBoard = new PlayBoard(12);
        playBoard.setParties(new Player("Lea"),
                             new Player("Susan"),
                             new Player("Daria"));

        List<Thread> threads = playBoard.players.stream()
            .map(player -> new Thread(player::play))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        threads.forEach(Thread::start);
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your play() method is not thread-safe, because the lock is dropped for each iteration of the `while` loop.  The `while` needs to be *inside* the `synchronized` block to be thread-safe. Also, ignoring InterruptedException means your code is a *rogue thread* that cannot be terminated.  The only correct response to an interrupt is to exit the loop.  The easiest way to do this is the place the entire body of the method inside the `try` block.

Comment: VGR, thanks. Agree about both points, but the interruption processing in the snippet. To manage it correctly we need, at the first glance, to remove the interrupted player from the queue (let's say one has an urgent phone call and cannot proceed the game), handle current player pointer, handle the 'not enough players now' case. All that definitely is out of scope. Ignoring makes no good in production and must be processed with extreme care, but not here, And the easiest way to leave the loop is 'return' statement, isn't it?

Comment: Technically, writing zero lines of code is easier than writing one line of code.  The try/catch has to be present regardless, so placing all the code inside the try block means the loop will exit automatically when an InterruptedException is encountered.  No need for a return or break.

Comment: Clarifying: you can use the `return` statement right here in the `wait` - interrupting `catch` block where it stands. There is absolutely no need to cover _the entire body of the method_ with `try/catch` as it brings no additional control and decreases readability. The interruption should be controlled by the runnable implementation on purpose by periodically (in a loop) asking for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`. Such a design allows you to implement escaping login in an algorithmic, not exceptional manner. Nevetherless, interruption handling still is not the point in this topic.